# Is the combination of actions in this sentence correct?

Tags: grammar

The sentence:

> This essay will analyse this topic from both points of view and express my opinion.

I think might be grammatically incorrect because it combines two separate actions while the coordination sounds ambiguous to me.

Alternatively, are these the more correction versions?

> This essay will analyze this topic from both points of view and then express my opinion.

> This essay will analyze this topic from both points of view, offering an analysis, and conclude with my opinion.

Comment: I've never heard this rule: where did you learn it? What exactly did it say? Any grammar book will tell you it's fine to combine actions with "and", e.g. "[He switched off the television and went to bed.](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/and)"

Comment: If you're not happy with any of the above, perhaps "In this essay I will analyze this topic from both points of view and express my/an opinion."

Comment: Note how @DjinTonic returns agency to you, rather than "This essay will analyse ... and express my opinion." The essay will express it, not you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is fine. The structure of the sentence is:

> This essay will [[analyse this topic from both points of view] and [express my opinion]].

The conjunction is joining two verb phrases, which is perfectly acceptable.

But it does *sound* quite bad. I think that this is because one typically expects "both" and "and" to go together, so one might initially parse the sentence as:

> This essay will analyse this topic from [both [points of view] and [express my opinion]].

On *this* reading, of course, the sentence lacks parallelism and makes no logical sense.